# Сервер под приложение на android

Tags: android, сервер

На чем лучше написать серверную часть для приложения под android?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72550/discussion-on-question-by-jeron-----android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем вам писать сервер для приложения андроид? Вы можете спокойно использовать то, что уже имеется. Зачем изобретать велосипед? Серверы apache, ngnix достаточно хорошо справляются со своими задачами. Но если очень уж нужно, то смотрите в сторону сокетов.

```
public String connection(String URI, int method, String data, String params){
    System.out.println("BEGIN HTTPS");
    String line = "";
    String content_encoding = null;
    try{
        URL url;
        if(method == GET && data != null){
            url = new URL(URI+"?"+data);
        }else{
            url = new URL(URI);
        }
        HttpsURLConnection huc = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        huc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        huc.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        huc.setDoOutput(true);
        huc.setDoInput(true);
        if(method == GET){
            huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
        }else if(method == POST){
            huc.setRequestMethod("POST");
        }
        if(params != null){
            applyParamsToConnect(huc, params);
        }
        if(method == POST){
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(huc.getOutputStream()));
            bw.write(data);
            bw.flush();
        }
        last_code = huc.getResponseCode();
        content_encoding = huc.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding");
        BufferedReader br = null;
        if(content_encoding == null){
            content_encoding = "NULL_CONTENT";
        }
        if(content_encoding.contains("gzip")){
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(huc.getInputStream())));
        }else{
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(huc.getInputStream()));
        }
        while(br.ready()){
            line = line+br.readLine()+"\n";
        }
        System.out.println("Код ответа сервера: "+last_code);
        if(last_code == 302){
            System.out.println("ПОЗИЦИЯ ПЕРЕНАПРАВЛЕНИЯ: "+huc.getHeaderField("Location"));
            redirect = huc.getHeaderField("Location"); //Глобальная переменная
        }
        System.out.println("Заголовки ответа: "+huc.getHeaderFields().toString());
        //System.out.println("Тип контента: "+content_encoding);
        //System.out.println("Контент: \n"+line);
        br.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return line;
}
```

Вот код скрипта выполняющегося на сервере

```
<?php 
     $data = $_POST['data'];
     $json1 = "some1";
     $json2 = "some2";
     if($data === "val1"){
        echo $json1;
     }elseif($data === "val2"){
        echo $json2;
     }
?>
```

Comment: т.е. Апачи вполне справится с задачей? Просто хочу реализовать клиент-серверное приложение.

Comment: а в интернете я сколько искал и не могу определиться в этом вопросе.

Comment: Конечно. Приложение может образаться к серверу apache или ngnix. На них может быть написан php скрипт, который будет выдавать приложению ответ в виде, например JSON. Этот ответ может быть с легкостью обработан стандартным API андроида. И никаких проблем не будет.

Comment: Скопировал код из одного из своих приложений. Смотрите первый ответ.

Comment: Лучше бы сразу забить на этот `HttpURLConnection`, так как его в андроиде нужно прятать в `AsyncTask`. А это ой как много кода и плохо. Фу. Юзайте `Retrofit` или `Volley`

Comment: Почему же? Можно спокойно обернуть этот метод в Thread и никаких проблем с использованием не будет.

Comment: @Flippy Начинающему юзать `Retrofit/Volley`? Чтобы потом на собеседовании не ответить на вопрос о том, как формируется обычный `GET` запрос? Лучше остановиться пока на `HttpURLConnection`, почувствовать боль работы с `AsyncTask` и попытаться сделать качествено на `Thread`. А потом уже модные библиотеки использовать.

Comment: @Vladimir Parfenov, ах да, вы правы. Я натерпелся в свое время ;) Кстати, надо вернуться в эту тему, а то забыл все уже.

Answer (score 1):

Раз вы только учитесь, то не советую вам использовать открытые API. 
Например, [github](https://developer.github.com/v3/) или [vk](https://vk.com/dev/methods).